# How to search previously executed commands in the Julia REPL?

Tags: julia

Is there a quick way to search old commands which were run in the Julia REPL? Using the up arrow to go back in time seems to have a limit on its history and it is also quite cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the five REPL models available in Julia is the "Search mode" which allows you to search through previously executed commands from the REPL. You can click "Control" + "r" to open search mode like is shown below:

```
(reverse-i-search)`':
```

There is also a forward search available with "Control" + "s". You can read more about Julia's REPL Search mode here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/REPL/#Search-modes

Answer (score 2):

Checkout: https://kristofferc.github.io/OhMyREPL.jl/latest/features/fzf/#Fuzzy-REPL-history-search

Which will be easier to use than `reverse-i-search`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to "real" search, you can also enter the beginning of a previous line and scroll up in the history (using ↑ or Ctrl-P) to switch between all previously entered lines starting with the same prefix.

So, if you had previously entered `x = some_complicated_expression`, you can write `x =`  and go up until the line you were looking for appears.